# JavaScript extract between two strings not working inside map function

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML & JavaScript code:
I'm trying to extract every debtor name and his address.

```js
function extractBetween(string){
    var start_pos = string.indexOf('\tDebtor Names:\t') + 1;
    var end_pos = string.indexOf('\tSecured Party Names:\t',start_pos);
    var extract = string.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
    return extract;
}
var array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table[width="98%"] table:nth-child(1) tbody')).map(
    x => JSON.stringify(x.innerText.trim())
);
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i]);
    console.log(extractBetween(array[i]));
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="98%" align="CENTER"><tbody><tr><td>
        <table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4C1" align="left"><font size="-1">  4501.</font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Debtor Names:</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b> LOFLI</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>650USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Secured Party Names:</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>METROP</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>99 USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4"></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" width="60" align="left"></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>CTC</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>330USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135863332</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> FS</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965587</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202007246956275</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/24/2020</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </td></tr></tbody></table>,<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135863332</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> FS</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965587</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202007246956275</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/24/2020</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>,<table border="1" width="98%" align="CENTER"><tbody><tr><td>
        <table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4C1" align="left"><font size="-1">  4502.</font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Debtor Names:</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b> CHAI</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>54 SUNRISE USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" width="60" align="left"></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>SIK</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>54 10304, USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4"></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Secured Party Names:</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>METRO</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>PARK AVE.USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" width="60" align="left"></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>CTC</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135864485</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> FS</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965614</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202006055863845</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 06/05/2020</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </td></tr></tbody></table>,<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135864485</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> FS</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965614</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202006055863845</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 06/05/2020</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>,<table border="1" width="98%" align="CENTER"><tbody><tr><td>
        <table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4C1" align="left"><font size="-1">  4503.</font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Debtor Names:</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b> PAN.</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Secured Party Names:</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>CTC</b></font></td>
        <td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>USA</b></font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        <table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135866148</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> FS</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202105105737065</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 05/10/2021</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1" color="RED"> NA * </font></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </td></tr></tbody></table>,<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
        <tbody><tr>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
        <th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135866148</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> FS</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> </font></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202105105737065</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 05/10/2021</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
        <td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1" color="RED"> NA * </font></td>
        </tr>
        </tbody></table>
```

I can see every table text extracted from the first `console.log` but the specific text I need from the function `extractBetween` is always empty even though I tested the function and it is working. Any help on how to solve this issue please? Thanks.

Comment: You might want to anonymise the data in your example, what's there right now looks like it should potentially be kept private. E.g. The name/address of the M.D in the console log seems distinctly not-public information.

Comment: Those data are available in the public domain without any login, just a form search. This is why I considered that it is ok to put data as it is.

Comment: I cleaned the data for privacy, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
function extractBetween(string){
        var breakatstring = "Debtor Names:";
    var start_pos = string.indexOf(breakatstring) + breakatstring.length;
    var end_pos = string.indexOf('Secured Party Names:');
    var extract = string.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
    extract = extract.split(/\t|\\t|\n|\\n/g).filter(n => n);
    return extract;
}
var array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table[width="98%"] table:nth-child(1) tbody')).map(
    x => JSON.stringify(x.innerText.trim())
);
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    //console.log(array[i]);
    console.log(extractBetween(array[i]));
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="98%" align="CENTER"><tbody><tr><td>
<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td bgcolor="FFF4C1" align="left"><font size="-1">  4501.</font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Debtor Names:</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b> LOFLIN HOLDINGS INC.</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>650 WEST 42ND STREET, APARTMENT 2504, NEW YORK, NY 10036, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Secured Party Names:</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>METROPOLITAN COMMERCIAL BANK</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>99 PARK AVE., 4TH FLOOR, NEW YORK, NY 10016, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4"></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" width="60" align="left"></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>C T CORPORATION SYSTEM, AS REPRESENTATIVE</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>330 N BRAND BLVD, SUITE 700; ATTN: SPRS, GLENDALE, CA 91203, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135863332</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> Financing Statement</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35827193&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965587</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35956410&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202007246956275</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/24/2020</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=39873857&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td></tr></tbody></table>,<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135863332</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> Financing Statement</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35827193&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965587</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35956410&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202007246956275</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/24/2020</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=39873857&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>,<table border="1" width="98%" align="CENTER"><tbody><tr><td>
<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td bgcolor="FFF4C1" align="left"><font size="-1">  4502.</font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Debtor Names:</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b> CHAITANYA SIKHARAM, M.D.</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>54 SUNRISE TERRACE, STATEN ISLAND, NY 10304, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" width="60" align="left"></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>SIKHARAM, CHAITANYA</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>54 SUNRISE TERRACE, STATEN ISLAND, NY 10304, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4"></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Secured Party Names:</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>METROPOLITAN COMMERCIAL BANK</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>99 PARK AVE., 4TH FLOOR, NEW YORK, NY 10016, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" width="60" align="left"></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>C T CORPORATION SYSTEM, AS REPRESENTATIVE</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>330 N BRAND BLVD, SUITE 700; ATTN: SPRS, GLENDALE, CA 91203, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135864485</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> Financing Statement</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35829415&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965614</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35956434&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202006055863845</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 06/05/2020</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=39574065&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td></tr></tbody></table>,<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135864485</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> Financing Statement</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35829415&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 201808065965614</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 08/06/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Assignment</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 2</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35956434&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202006055863845</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 06/05/2020</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=39574065&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>,<table border="1" width="98%" align="CENTER"><tbody><tr><td>
<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td bgcolor="FFF4C1" align="left"><font size="-1">  4503.</font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Debtor Names:</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="left"><font size="-1"><b> PANSTAR PROPANE CORP.</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="FFF4D4" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>23 GRASSY POINT ROAD, STONY POINT, NY 10980, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" scope="row" width="60" align="left"><font size="-2"><b>Secured Party Names:</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="left"><font size="-1"><b>C T CORPORATION SYSTEM, AS REPRESENTATIVE</b></font></td>
<td bgcolor="LIGHTGREY" align="center"><font size="-1"><b>330 N BRAND BLVD, SUITE 700; ATTN: SPRS, GLENDALE, CA 91203, USA</b></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135866148</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> Financing Statement</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35830375&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202105105737065</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 05/10/2021</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1" color="RED"> NA * </font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</td></tr></tbody></table>,<table align="CENTER" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File no.</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">File Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Lapse Date</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Filing Type</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Pages</font></th>
<th scope="col" bgcolor="#339999"><font size="-1">Image</font></th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 201807135866148</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2018</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> Financing Statement</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="FFF4D4"><font size="-1"> <a href="https://appext20.dos.ny.gov/ASPIMGView/imgview.aspx?pdocid=35830375&amp;pidmname=DEFAULT&amp;pApp=UCC " target="_blank">  View </a></font></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 202105105737065</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 05/10/2021</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 07/13/2023</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> Termination</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1"> 1</font></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="LIGHTGREY"><font size="-1" color="RED"> NA * </font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

It seems some of your `\t` and `\n` are double escaped. With the regex I added to the replace of extract its displaying correctly.

This will also remove empty values from the extract array. Where every EVEN item in the array is the debtor name and every ODD item is the address of the debtor name.

Comment: You answer works as I want if I remove this line extract = extract.replace(/\t|\\t|\n|\\n/g, ""); otherwise I will have just spaces and no way to know debtors from addresses. Thanks.

Comment: @DevDev I've just updated the answer to provide you with a better result. Try it out now

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on `\t` for string match inside `indexOf`.

Try this:

```
function extractBetween(string){
    var start_pos = string.indexOf("Debtor Names:");
    var end_pos = string.indexOf('Secured Party Names:',start_pos);
    var extract = string.substring(start_pos,end_pos);
    return extract.trim();
}
var array = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('table[width="98%"] table:nth-child(1) tbody')).map(
    x => JSON.stringify(x.innerText.trim())
);
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    console.log(array[i]);
    console.log(extractBetween(array[i]));
}
```

Comment: I need to use JSON.stringify to have something to rely on (\n or \t) when I will put each debtor name and address in an array. If I go with your solution, I will have only spaces and I won't be able to know how to separate debtors names from addresses.

Comment: Ok, you can keep `JSON.stringify` but you should not use `\t` inside `indexOf` because you may have undesired results, I modify my answer.